# Ubuntu and racadm

Tags: server, dell

I recently purchased a used poweredge 1850 server and it came with a DRAC card. After wiping the HDD and installing ubuntu server 12.04.3 LTS amd64 on it, I am now trying to gain access to the DRAC which I believe is version 4. I have properly configured the DRAC to use it's own IP on my LAN and when I point my browser to the IP address, I am greeted with the DRAC login page (it has the dell logo and everything). However, after trying the credentials of root/calvin, I was denied access. So I think that the previous owners had set their own password. After doing some reading, it appears that I can reset the credentials to the default using

```
racadm config -g cfgUserAdmin -o cfgUserAdminPassword -i 1 newpassword
```

but upon entering the command, I get this error:

```
bash: /usr/sbin/racadm: No such file or directory
```

This holds true even if I run

```
sudo su
```

prior to running the racadm command.

If, however, I run

```
sudo racadm config -g cfgUserAdmin -o cfgUserAdminPassword -i 1 newpassword
```

there are no errors. Yet, when I try to log into the DRAC via the web interface using the credentials of root/newpassword I am still not granted access.

I installed the dell utilities via the guide at https://wiki.ubuntu.com/HardwareSupportMachinesServersDellNotes. I first tried to install the 64 bit version that is on the dell repositories, but after that was unsuccessful, I just followed the guide verbatim. No errors were produced in either case. I even followed the information at the bottom of the guide by executing

```
sudo pppd /dev/ttyS1 1382400 crtscts noipdefault noauth lock persist connect 'chat -v "" CLIENT CLIENTSERVER "\\c"'
```

but obviously, replacing the /dev/ttyS1 with the correct information for my system.

```
ls -l /usr/sbin/ | grep racadm
```

yields

```
-rwxr-xr-x 1 root    root        87930 Sep 16 04:03 racadm
```

I have tried these credentials after each attempt of changing the password:

root/calvin

root/newpassword

admin/calvin

admin/newpassword

All have been unsuccessful. What is the next course of action that I should take?

Answer (score 1):

As a workaround, `racadm` is available on the "Dell Systems Build and Update Utility" bootable CD. For my PE 2950, I used version "6.5.0,173_A01" (filename "cdu_1.6_core_173_A01.iso") from 
http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/19/DriverDetails?driverId=NF1CT

To make sure you get the right download for your system, start at http://www.dell.com/support/drivers/us/en/555/ServiceTag/XXXXXXX (where XX... is your Dell "service tag"), then search under "Systems Management".

Answer (score 1):

Reboot the server, and pressing CTRL-E during bootup (at the console), takes you to a BIOS version of the racadm admin. There you are able to set a username/password.